# Connecting to clients under ZeroTier router via Windows client?

Tags: windows, networking, openwrt

I setup ZeroTier on my home OpenWRT router.

I can connect to devices in my home, form a Android ZeroTier client.

However I cannot connect to home devices from my workplace ZeroTier Windows client. This workplace Windows client could only see same level ZeroTier clients (my phone and my home router)

The graph of my network setup:
[image: zerotier graph]

Flow rules in https://my.zerotier.com/network/ only have `accept;`.

My Windows zerotier one looks like:

[image]

Windows PC setting in zerotier central looks like:

[image]

*UPDATE:*
Answering grawity's questions:

Info from zerotier-cli on Windows client:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>zerotier-cli info
200 info ef51c862db 1.2.12 TUNNELED
```

If I try to trace route to `172.22.1.1`, it seems my workplace gateway (10.10.15.241) router takes it:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>tracert 172.22.1.1
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  my.router [10.10.15.241]
  2     1 ms     2 ms     2 ms  172.22.1.1
```

I tried to ping `10.144.0.209` and `172.22.1.1`, and use Wireshark to inspect.
When pinging `10.144.0.209`, ICMP packages only go through ZeroTier interface. When pinging `172.22.1.1`, ICMP packages only go to my physical LAN interface.

The firewall setting in my OpwnWRT router looks like:

[image: firewall]
`zeroTierVpn` is the zone of the ZeroTier interface.

**Question:**

What should I do so my Windows zerotier client could connect to my home device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I need to manually add a route on Windows client.
I use:

```
route add 172.22.0.0 MASK 255.255.0.0 10.144.0.209 IF 35
          ^home subnet                ↑               ^ZertTier interface number
                                      IP of my OpenWRT gateway router
```

After that I could successfully trace route:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>tracert 172.22.1.2
  1   215 ms   124 ms   115 ms  10.144.0.22
  2   122 ms   117 ms   116 ms  172.22.1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

In its default configuration, ZeroTier transfers raw Ethernet frames without filtering or modification. Treat it as an Ethernet connection, and investigate it the same way.

1. Does the configuration at https://my.zerotier.com/ have any "flow rules" other than `accept;`?
2. Do workplace computers have a route to your home subnet (and is it via ZeroTier)?
3. Does that route have the correct 'gateway' parameter (i.e. is not an on-link route, but rather a gateway route via the OpenWRT router)?
4. Does a packet capture tool (such as tcpdump or Wireshark) show packets being sent over the ZeroTier interface when running e.g. `ping -t 172.22.1.1`?
5. Does a packet capture tool on the OpenWRT router, and on home devices themselves, show packets being received from your workplace computers? On the router, check separately the ZeroTier interface and the LAN interface.
6. What source IP address do workplace computers use when they try to send packets to home? Is it the ZeroTier IP address or the workplace LAN IP address? The packet capture tool in previous steps will show this.
7. If packets reach the router but not the LAN – does the router's firewall allow them to be forwarded there? Often packet forwarding between interfaces is blocked until you configure otherwise.
8. If packets reach the LAN device, does it generate a reply? (i.e. if you ping it and it receives an ICMP Echo Request via its ethernet, does a packet capture tool show it sending out an ICMP Echo Reply back?)
9. If step 4 showed that the inbound packets are coming from a workplace IP address (instead of ZeroTier address), does the router have a route there via ZeroTier?

   (LAN devices will have the default route and that should be enough.)
10. Similarly to step 3, does the packet capture tool on the router show the response packets going in from LAN and going out via ZeroTier?

Note: In its default configuration, OpenWRT *performs SNAT* on packets forwarded between certain interfaces. If connections "out" work fine, but connections "in" do not, the answer is almost always a) the firewall, b) missing routes and the router performing NAT to cover it up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have updated my question, hope those information could help resolving?